# How to create a file in python if it does not exists

Tags: python

I have the following method in Python.

```
def get_rum_data(file_path, query):
    if file_path is not None and query is not None:
        command = FETCH_RUM_COMMAND_DATA % (constants.RUM_JAR_PATH, 
                                            constants.RUM_SERVER, file_path, 
                                            query)
        print command
        execute_command(command).communicate()
```

Now inside `get_rum_data` I need to create the file if it does not exists, if it exists I need to append the data. How to do that in python.

I tried, `open(file_path, 'w')` , which gave me an exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils.py", line 180, in <module>
    get_rum_data('/User/rokumar/Desktop/sample.csv', '\'show tables\'')
  File "utils.py", line 173, in get_rum_data
    open(file_path, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/User/rokumar/Desktop/sample.csv'
```

I though open would create  file in write mode.

Comment: You'll often see this error if the parent directory (/User/rokumar/Desktop) does not exist. My guess is that /User should be /Users...

Comment: Create an empty project that has this single line `open('/path/to/file', 'w')`. Does it fail?

Comment: You are right . It should be Users

Comment: Another useful feature for resolving the current user's base directory (works for unix, linux and windows) is using [expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) from the ``os.path`` module.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if all directories in `file_path` exist prior to trying to write a file.

```
import os

file_path = '/Users/Foo/Desktop/bar.txt' 
print os.path.dirname(file_path)  
# /Users/Foo/Desktop

if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(file_path)):
    os.mkdirs(os.path.dirname(file_path))  
    # recursively create directories if necessary

with open(file_path, "a") as my_file:
    # mode a will either create the file if it does not exist
    # or append the content to its end if it exists.
    my_file.write(your_text_to_append)
```

**-- Edit: Small and probably unnecessary extension --**

***expanduser:***
In your case, as it turned out that the initial problem was a missing `s` in the path to the user directory, there is a useful feature for resolving the current users base directory (works for unix, linux and windows): see [expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) from the os.path module. With that you could write your path as `path = '~/Desktop/bar.txt'` and the tilde (~) will be expanded just like on your shell. (with the additional benefit that if you started your script from another user it would then expand to her home directory.

***App config directory:***
Since in most cases it is not desirable to write a file to the desktop (*nix systems for instance might not have a desktop installed), there is a great utility function in the [click package](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click). If you look at the [`get_app_dir() function on Github`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/blob/master/click/utils.py#L382), you can see how they provide expanding to an appropriate app dir and supporting multiple operating systems (the function has no dependencies besides the `WIN` variable that is defined in the `_compat.py` module as `WIN = sys.platform.startswith('win')` and the `_posixify()` function defined on line 17. Often that's a good starting point for defining an app directory to store certain data in.

Answer (score 0):

It shall be as simple as:

```
fname = "/User/rokumar/Desktop/sample.csv"
with open(fname, "a") as f:
    # do here what you want
# it will get closed at this point by context manager
```

But I would suspect, that you are trying to use not existing directory. Usually, "a" mode creates the file if it can be created.

Make sure, the directory exists.

Comment: I think the write mode needs to be ``a`` if the OP wants to append new data rather than to truncate everything in the existing file?

Comment: OP said it needs to treat the exception if the directory doesn't exist

Comment: @IuriGuilherme - No, OP did not ask in his question to create the directory. It only asked for creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

def get_rum_data(file_path, query):
    if file_path is not None and query is not None:

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(file_path)) and os.path.dirname(file_path) not in [None, '', ' ']:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path))
        if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'x') as fp:
                pass

        command = FETCH_RUM_COMMAND_DATA % (constants.RUM_JAR_PATH, 
                                            constants.RUM_SERVER, file_path, 
                                            query)
        print command
        execute_command(command).communicate()
```

Bibliography:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path

---

Just creating an empty file if it doesn't exist:

```py
if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'x') as fp:
        pass
```

Creating the file's full absolute path recursively if any directory or subdirectory doesn't exist:

```py
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(file_path)) and os.path.dirname(file_path) not in [None, '', ' ']:
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path))
```

If you don't include the test for empty dirnames (which is the case when **file_path** is 'example.txt' instead of '/path/to/example.txt', it will raise an exception.